# Candy Box Dilemma

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

There was a box of candy on the table.  Ali ate half the candy.  Miranda came along and took two-thirds of it.  Jane decided she wanted some, so she took three-fourths of the remaining candy.  Micayla took one piece and Alejandro took the last single piece.  How many pieces of candy were there to begin with?

Comment: Lisa, You are heartily welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. We all want more people to join this community. But here, when you are asking something, you supposed to show that you have attempted a bit on the task, OK? And, before posting such minor problems, better you try hard on the problem, that will help you more than merely getting some answers from other peoples. And, WELCOME, once again.

Comment: Ok, I did it using an algebraic method, but got stuck:  This is what I did:  1/2x + 2/3x(1/2) + 3/4x(1/3)(1/2) +2 =1/2x +1/3x +1/8x + 2 = 23/24x +2 and I am lost after this.

Comment: All that's left for you to do, Lisa, is go $(23/24)x+2=x$ and then solve for $x$. Personally, I think algebra is overkill on a problem that can be solved just using arithmetic, but, whatever floats your boat....

Comment: So, have you found any of the answers/comments helpful? or do you still have questions about the candy box?

Comment: Earth to Lisa: come in, please.

Answer (score 1):

let box have M candy.

ali ate half , so it remains $\frac{M}{2}$

miranda took $\frac{2}{3}$ from $\frac{M}{2}$, so it remains $\frac{1}{3}$ from $\frac{M}{2}$ and that is $\frac{M}{6}$

jane took $\frac{3}{4}$ from $\frac{M}{6}$ , so it remains $\frac{1}{4}$ from $\frac{M}{6}$ and that is $\frac{M}{24}$

micayla and alejandro took one each so $\frac{M}{24}=2$

from there you get $M=48$

Answer (score 1):

There was 1 piece when Alejandro came along, so there were 2 pieces when Micayla stopped by, so there were $4\times2=8$ pieces when Jane stocked up (she took three-fourths, so what was left after she acted was one-fourth of what she found, so what she found was four times what she left for Micayla to find, so, 8). There were three times that many, so, $24$ pieces when Miranda stuffed her face, so $48$ pieces when Ali set to work.